# What do I need to consider when choosing a GenAI system?

Tags: capabilities

It is hard to figure out the limitations and issues about various AI tools. Having used a couple of AI tools already, I usually get a bit lost in the documentation and terms of use.

I would like to know if there are factors that are common between all the current tools that can serve as a good starting point: a shortlist that I can use when considering a new GenAI system, to assess what it might be useful for by what it is, rather than how it is marketed.

What should be on this list?

Comment: Please make this question practical, detailed question about using a specific GenAI tool. P.S. Maybe this question is better fit for [ai.se].

Comment: Changing the title and tags is good but should match the question body content. Remember, the title should summarize the question body; tags should be added based on what is being asked, in other words, the core of the question body content.

Comment: answers go in answer posts and not in question posts. also, I can't parse your title. please make it more understandable.

Comment: I think it's worth re-opening this question, because there aren't many more things that apply to _all_ GenAI systems; we won't have the "hundreds of possible answers" curse that many list questions have. If this question works well, there could be similar questions for more specific kinds of system (e.g. text-generation systems; text-based knowledge assistants).

Comment: @MichaelLai Please consider posting the four bullet points from your first revision as answers – preferably separate answers, so they can be voted on separately. (If any of them were closely-related, I'd suggest putting them in the same answer, but none of these examples are.) Also consider elaborating on them: what you've written is only really useful to someone who already knows what to look for and how to look for it.

Comment: I feel that even if some guidance could be given, at the very best this should be restricted to a specific type of generated content. Are we talking about language models, image generation, voice, music.... ?

Answer (score 0):

> What is a good checklist to use when working with an AI tool for the first time to understand its limitations?

Need to understand the quality of its prediction/generation: Find some [benchmark](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.05613.pdf), understand the failure cases/limitations, go through non-cherry-picked examples, etc.